# Is it ungrammatical to start a description of the functionality of a mechanism with a bare infinitive?

Tags: grammaticality, technical, bare-infinitive

In technical documentation (I am mainly referring to the documentation for the source code of a computer program), this pattern seems quite common:

```
function MakeNFrobbers(int n):    
    Construct a list of 10 Frobbers.
```

However, someone recently claimed that this was not proper English and changed "**Construct** a list..." to "**Creates** a list...". The reasoning they gave was as follows:

- "This guy construct" -> no predicate
- "This guy creates" -> better

With "this guy" being unwritten in the typical clipped style of technical documentation.

To be clear, I'm not suggesting that the former is correct while the latter is not; both sound correct to my ear. However, I can't explain why using "construct" is grammatically correct in this context. The only counterpoint I could offer was:

- "This guy **allows you to** construct" -> also correct

Is the former version using the bare infinitive ungrammatical and the second option the correct way, or are both correct? If both are correct, what is the rule that covers this particular case in regards to using a bare infinitive?

Comment: As each example (without the implied subject) is a fragment, concern about grammatical correctness seems tedious - provided the same convention is used throughout. *The above function will* **Construct/Create** vs *The above function* **Constructs/Creates** - surely, an argument can be made for either, but the time is probably better spent elsewhere. :)

Comment: Well, some fragments are more equal than others.

Comment: If that is the case, the function is misnamed also and should be `MakesNFrobbers`. Ha!

Comment: Or *MakeFrobberList()*

Comment: Besides what @Kaz answered, which is correct and relevant, this is essentially a **style** question. Be consistent with whichever style you choose. If you don't have a style guide to follow, choose whichever style you like, as long as the meaning is clear. The choice posed here is not about grammar - both *construct* and *creates* are grammatical as used here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd take the bare infinitive form as short for:

```
  What function MakeNFrobbers(int n) does is construct a list of 10 Frobbers.
```

This is a pseudo-cleft sentence, and it does take a bare infinitive after the "is".

Comment: Are cleft sentences considered to be ungrammatical or bad form in formal English? I can't seem to find a definitive answer.

Comment: No.  As a linguist, I don't really deal with "bad form", but I don't really see what's wrong with such sentences.  Analyses are proposed for both cleft and pseudo-clleft sentences in McCawley's *The Syntactic Phenomena of English*.

Comment: @Meta They are not considered to be in formal English.

Comment: @Kaz I guess "formal" as in formal technical documentation.

Answer (score 2):

It is not a bare infinitive, but rather an imperative. It's paraphrasing what the computer is being told to do.

It is no less grammatical than a sentence like "Combine all ingredients in a bowl" in a cooking recipe.

Comment: It's not an imperative, because imperatives can take an optional "please".  However, you wouldn't add that to "construct a list" in the example.

Comment: @GregLee It takes please. "Please construct a list of ten integers." "Please combine the ingredients in a bowl."  It's just comical/superfluous in that context.

Comment: Basically it's ambiguous to me. We can read a recipe as a bunch of imperatives. Or we can read it as a collection of cleft sentences which can be preceded  by elided clauses such as *"What you do next is:"*.